# Grouping Data in a Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, grouping

I've got a really big matrix which I should "upscale" (i.e.: create another matrix where the elements of the first are grouped 40-by-40). For every 40-by-40 group I should evaluate a series of parameters (i.e.: frequencies, average and standard deviation).

I'm quite sure I can make such thing with a loop, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant vectorized method...

Comment: What exactly is "to create another matrix where the elements of the first are grouped 40-by-40". Do you mean a three-dimensional array of size 40x40xN? You could use `reshape` for that

Comment: Think of the matrix as a image of M*N pixel, I would basically want to create a lower resolution "image" where eache pixel of the new image is composed by grouping 40 elements of the older matrix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) useful. This command allows you to apply a function (e.g. `@mean`, `@std` etc.) to each distinct block in a 2D matrix.

Comment: +1 in case you need to apply multiple functions on the 40x40 blocks, perhaps you could also use the related `im2col` function: reshape once into columns, apply multiple functions (preferably in a vectorized manner), rearrange results into downscaled image

Comment: Blockproc looks great! Can it also group the elements besides applying functions? Or can I group them with a "group" function or something like that? Maybe I can script it myself...